# Django M2M with "self" through int. table, how to get related items

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am trying to establish some M2M relation in one of my models. Django asked me to put related_name argument to some of the fields, and I put them. However, I am now confused with how to get related items. Here is my models simplified.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # other fields
    relevancy = models.ManyToManyField("self",through="Traffic",symmetrical=False,related_name="relevant",blank=True)

    #some method definitions

class Traffic(models.Model):
    tfrom = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="tfrom")
    tto = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="tto")
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

This is to be a user tendency analyzing, and giving suggestions to other users tool. The part I am confused is the part where I get related post to the post in question. For example, when I choose Post, how do I get a set of post that made traffic from that post, or set of posts that trafficked to that post etc. Here is my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070917/django-sum-of-fields-in-intermediary-model-with-given-queryset) that I posted before.

PS: English is not my main language, sorry if my question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the intermediate model definition. The firs FK of the intermediate model is what defines the 'principal' access, so

```
a_post.relevancy.all()
```

is the set of all the `Post` instances with a traffic **from `a_post` to them** .

```
a_post.relevant.all()
```

is the set of all the `Post` instances with a traffic **from them to `a_post`**.

You should really think about your naming conventions, it's pretty confusing. Something in the line of

```
links = models.ManyToManyField("self",
             through="Traffic",
             symmetrical=False,
             related_name="referrers",
             blank=True)
```

---

The key is in the django sorce code:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1059

```
                    # If this is an m2m-intermediate to self,
                    # the first foreign key you find will be
                    # the source column. Keep searching for
                    # the second foreign key.
```

So you have that

```
s1 = set(my_post.relevancy.all())
s2 = set(t.tto for t in my_post.tfrom.select_related('tto'))
assert not s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
```

In simpler SQL, the descriptor `p.relevancy` is getting all the `Post` instances where the ID is in

```
select traffic.tto_id where traffic.tfrom_id = my_post_id
```

Comment: By first, do you mean order of defining the field, or something else? For example, would it make difference if I define tto first and tfrom second?

Comment: Exactly. Fields are retrieved upon model initialization, and stored in a field list in the model's Meta class (not to be confused with the metaclass, that's another story), then the attribute on the instance is a "descriptor" that uses the field to get data. In any case, putting relevant names to things will help detecting this kind of issues, so in all cases you can check whether you are defining the correct names for things.